# Why does my Ionic Project display blank after I import IonIcons/icons on the top of the page using React Native

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IonApp, IonButton, IonCol, IonContent, IonGrid, IonHeader, IonIcon, IonInput, IonItem, IonLabel, IonRow, IonTitle, IonToolbar} from '@ionic/react';
import {calculatorOutline, refreshOutline} from 'ionicons/icons';
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */

/* Theme variables */


const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
        <IonHeader>
      <IonToolbar>
        <IonTitle>Bmi Calculator</IonTitle>
      </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent class="ion-padding">
      <IonGrid>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Your Height</IonLabel>
              <IonInput></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Your Weight</IonLabel>
              <IonInput></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
          </IonCol>
        </IonRow>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol className="ion-text-left">
            <IonButton>
              <IonIcon slot="start" icon={calculatorOutline} />
              Calculate
            </IonButton>
          </IonCol>
          <IonCol className="ion-text-right">
            <IonButton>
              <IonIcon slot="start" icon={refreshOutline} />
              Reset
            </IonButton>
          </IonCol>
        </IonRow>
      </IonGrid>
    </IonContent>
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

**This is my code for my project**

Before I import

```js
import {calculatorOutline, refreshOutline} from 'ionicons/icons';
```

everything went well and display the thing it should display. But when I import that snippet of code, it display blank as below. So I am just wondering what did I miss and where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do they belong to there ? If you want to implement an icon just import the main module IonIcon and than its just <ion-icon name='calculator'></ion-icon>

Comment: replying to @StefaniToto, I have tried using ```<ion-icon></ion-icon>``` as you mentioned, but its appeared that 'ion-icon' property does not exist on type 'JSX.IntristicElements'